# Symfony2: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: symfony, caching, memory-limit

I am using Symfony2. I use below command to clear the cache.

```
 app/console ca:cl
```

when this command runs after some seconds it shows me error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
64 bytes) in D:\wamp\www\wenweipo\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Print.php 
on line 22
```

I found some solution but that does not works for me.I change the Memory Limit in `php.ini` to

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

I also set it to `-1` but same problem. After that I use below command that works for me

```
 php -d memory_limit=256M app/console cache:clear
```

now the problem is that this command takes a lot of time (2 to 3 minutes) to clear cache.Is there any solution?
Also sometimes when I open a page it shows me `The connection was reset` and I hit page many times and it works.
Is it the problem of cache?

Comment: If you are just wanting to clear the cache you can always just delete the individual folders in the `app/cache` (or `var/cache/ in the Symfony3 directory structure, I believe) directory.

Comment: directly deleting the folder does not resolve the second problem `The connection was reset`

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: After you change php.ini you need to restart apache "service apache2 restart" you maybe need to sudo it. Thats why your command works, because it directly applies the memory_limit change temporarily to your command. Your changes to php.ini havent been loaded yet.